# Loading a component inside a modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

i wanted to ask... is there any way to add the template "just the template" of other component in a modal?? I have a big form in a component and im just interested in the html... not in the component.ts! thank you

Comment: use ngx-boostrap modal. Refer [this](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably better to create a separate html for your modal just as in any other component, and just copy the html there. You could reference the same template within your modal component, but better to separate.

If you're trying to retrieve the components html via code, that would be messier and more complicated than just cntrl + c and cntrl + v

Comment: Thank you mate! yeah... i just decided to copy and paste the html from the other component... but i wanted to ask because maybe there was an easy solution :P angular always surprise me :P